# Where the Devil is my Applications .config file?

Tags: c#, winforms, configuration-files

All, I have a large application. This application uses a .config file to deal with its various settings. This is fine in development, and the .config file is found and working happily in the respective `\bin` folders (Release and Debug). I have written a NSIS installer an I am now running the app; it is working perfectly, saving settings, restoring settings and generally being a good LAD.

However, the 'MyApp.exe.config' is *not* where the settings are being written (I have checked and even deleted this so it could be recreated). It is also not in `...Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\MyApp`?

Where the Devil is my applications config file?

Thanks again for your time.

*Edit. I have printed out `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` and this points to the `Roaming` AppData directory above.*

Comment: Have you tried running a search for the file?

Comment: Do you get the MyApp.exe.config file at all, or are the settings not being written to the file?

Comment: Have you checked AppData\Local\MyApp?

Comment: No I don't think I do. I install a default one with the application, but when it is deleted it is not recreated so it is not in the application folder. I have tried all of the AppData directories...

Comment: Note. 'AppData\Local\MyApp' is not being created??

Comment: Does the NSIS installer actually install the config file anywhere? The application won't create one itself.

Comment: In the properties of App.Config file, chose build action as 'Content' and see if this helps

Comment: It might help if you post the relevant code. For example `OpenMachineConfiguration` vs `OpenExeConfiguration`

Comment: @ChrisChilvers yes it does install one. But, it should atomatically recreate itself if it is deleted and in the code you have the `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`. Also, the one that is install initially is not being used!?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration system for .net gets its settings from several locations.

General config comes from:

1. The first location is the machine.config file that ships with the .net framework.
2. The next location is the application's configuration file.

Next the settings API gets values from (using the default provider):

1. Hard-coded defaults when the app was compiled.
2. The application configuration file.
3. The user's settings file.

If the application's configuration file does not exist it will not be automatically created (doing so would be pointless since it would only contain the defaults the application already knows).

Saving the settings will however create a new user settings file as normal.

Comment: +1 for the clarification. If I set the Build Action of the app.config file in VS to 'None' and one does not exist - it will be created in the app.exe directory upon compilation - fine. However, when I am in Debug mode and I save the settings this does not update the .config in the Debug folder - but the settings are saved and restored - but where from!?

Comment: I did not say before, but thanks for your time... I have found the location of the .config files. They were in 'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MyApp.exe_Url_1owyoabipscybjfg241ka2iuuxnchccu` and other wierd directories. it seems that all versions; Debug, Release, Installed Version are all using the same .exe!?

Comment: Why would the application be placing the .config file here. Do you know of a way to change this?

Comment: Ah, that location would be isolated storage. This is normally where the user settings go and click once applications.

Comment: In VS goto Application Properties. On the tab 'Application' select 'Assembly Information...' - this is where the default path is build for the settings. Thanks for your help...